# ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to install pandas with CMD like this:

```
py -m pip install pandas-1.3.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Someone can help? Thanks..

Comment: Installing `numpy` with the latest Python, 3.10, is not yet working.  Stick with 3.9 if possible.